# ZIP Doesn't show in Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I created a new Azure Function using the Azure portal. I have the ZIP of my application code. I used below command to deploy the ZIP file to my Azure function. But when I go to Azure Functions -> Functions, it doesn't show anything.

[image]

This is the command I used to upload the ZIP file

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g my-resource-group -n my-funcation-app  --src "My-ZIP-File.zip"
```

After I execute the above command, it shows as succeeded.

```
"message": "Created via a push deployment",
"progress": "",
"provisioningState": "Succeeded"
```

Any idea why it doesn't show?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the below steps to do the zip deployment of Function App using CLI:

1. Created the .NET 6 Azure Functions locally and zipped using PowerShell Command:

```
C:\Users\krishna\source\repos\KrishNet6FunctionApp1205> Compress-Archive C:\Users\krishna\source\repos\KrishNet6FunctionApp1205 -DestinationPath ".\KrishNet6FunctionApp1205.zip" -CompressionLevel Optimal
```

2. Created .NET 6 Function App in Azure Portal > added the application setting `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT` to `true` and then deployed the local zipped function app to the Azure portal function app using the below command:

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g KrishnaTestRG -n KrishNet6App141-FunApp --src "C:/Users/krishna/source/repos/KrishNet6FunctionApp1205.zip"
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: No idea why it doesn't show to me

Comment: Have you set the `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT` to `true` in Azure Portal Function App Configuration before publishing?

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem on ZIP deployment and it turns out I uploaded the dotnet application code not the compiled code.

**Make sure:**

1. Contents in zip folder is the output of the compiled code.
   E.g. The contents after `dotnet build...` + `dotnet publish...`
   For NodeJS/Typescript, the contents after `tsc`/`npm run build` or whatever your build command is.
2. Check the app settings `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` and compare it to your hosting plan OS. Behind every function app there is a hosting plan.
   [More info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package)
3. You can debug downloading the zip file from azure portal. Go to **Overview** > **Download app content** and compare with you zip file to ensure it is being uploaded correctly.